# How do I access my servlet?

Tags: servlets, wildfly

My problem is, that I can not access my Servlet outside from my computer.

So. f.e. if I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/TestProject/test/`, it shows me my site. In my case there is some JSON- Code.

But if I want to access this Site from a computer that is remote, it doesn't work. So, again, f.e. if I go to `http://192.168.1.100:8080/TestProject/test/` (thats the IP from the computer where the WildFly- Server is started), it shows me nothing.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is your server listening this interface? Check this going to http://192.168.1.100 and see if you receive the default server message.

Comment: The server doesn't have to be listening this interface, because I am calling a HttpServlet. There I override the doGet() method..

Comment: if your server is not listening to 192.168.1.100, but just to 127.0.0.1, it won't even receive your request!!!

Comment: It does not matter if you write 192.168.1.100 or localhost or 127.0.0.1, because all means the same.

Comment: Not outside your computer...

Comment: So where do i have to put this in?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a loopback interface. It points to the computer where you are running, whatever it is. But assume you have two computers: 192.168.1.100 (where your application is hosted) and 192.168.1.101. If you are in 192.168.1.101 and try to access your application pointing your browser to http://192.168.1.100/TestProject/test/, this will work if, and only if, the web server at 192.168.1.100 is listening to the external interface.

Comment: Ok now I have added the line in the wildfly- server but it doesnt work either...

Comment: Any error message? Ot it just displays a blank page?

Comment: No its a connection- refused- error...

Comment: Are you sure the wildfly server is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! You have to start the WildFly- Server like that:

```
standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```